# How to use the query builder updateOrInsert method?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I'm trying to use `Eloquent's` `updateOrInsert` method to populate a a `mySQL` table, here's the migration:

```
Schema::create('myTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->time('value1')->nullable();
      $table->time('value2')->nullable();
      $table->time('value3')->nullable();
      $table->time('value4')->nullable();
    });
 }
```

Here's the controller:

```
   DB::connection('myDB')->table('myTable')
       ->updateOrInsert(
           [
               'id' => $request->id
           ],
           [
               'value1' => $request->value1,
               'value2' => $request->value2,
               'value3' => $request->value3,
               'value4' => $request->value4
           ]);
```

Here's the `axios.post()` request:

```
axios.post("populateMyTable/", {
        id: this.newTableEntry.id,
        value1: this.newTableEntry.value1,
        value2: this.newTableEntry.value2,
        value3: this.newTableEntry.value3,
        value4: this.newTableEntry.value4
    });
```

Now what i'm basically trying to achieve here is, if there's no record in the DB with the request id, create one & populate it. If there is, just update the values of said record.
However, what i'm struggling to make work is: If there's a record, i want to update only the values passed (let's say value1/value3), and dont touch the others (that's why i made them `nullable();`).

However, what happens is everytime i make a record, if some of the values are left empty, they get updated to null, regardless if they already contain data from previous entries, and if let's say i've previously populated value1 with `1`, and now insert `1` again, it does not become `2` (does not add the values from each request, just updates them). I feel like i'm going all wrong about this, but i'm fairly new to `mySQL` & `Eloquent`, so if anyone can help me out here it would be swell! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are not using eloquent, just query builder, btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for taking the time to answer my question, here's the solution i arrived at:

```
foreach ($request->requestData as $requestData) {
            $filteredRequestData = array_filter($requestData, function ($var) {
                return !is_null($var);
            });
            DB::connection('myDB')->table('myTable')
            ->updateOrInsert(
                [
                    'document_id' => $requestData['document_id'],
                    'row_id' => $requestData['row_id'],
                ],
                $filteredRequestData,
             );
```

The `foreach` loops the request data, the `array_filter` method filters thru the data and returns the non-null variables, and then i `updateOrInsert` it into the DB. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `array` only with the data you want to persist.

As @rahul-rathore said, use `updateOrCreate` method instead of `updateOrInsert`.

```
$data = [];
if ($request->value1) {
    $data['value1'] = $request->value1;
}
if ($request->value2) {
    $data['value2'] = $request->value2;
}

...

DB::connection('myDB')->table('myTable')
    ->updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => $request->id
        ],
        $data
    );
```

Comment: The problem is, there are like 15 fields that can be populated, and the user can choose to populate field 1 & 5 now, but field 7 & 10 next time. So i have to make it as dynamic as it can be, regardless of which field the user populated.

Comment: If you write one condition for each field it will work.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a shot!

Comment: Please use updateOrCreate instead of updateOrInsert

Answer (score 0):

Please use below example.

```
DB::connection('myDB')->table('myTable')
->updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'id' => $request->id
                ],
                [
                    'value1' => $request->value1,
                    'value2' => $request->value2,
                    'value3' => $request->value3,
                    'value4' => $request->value4
                ]
     );
```